# Change default tab in Product Edit Page

Tags: magento-1.9, products

If I open any product,by default "General" tab is showing.

Like below screenshot.

[image: General Tab]

But I want to open "Prices" tab by default.
Like below screenshot.

[image: Prices Tab]

Anyone can tell me how to do that.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check this class

> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs

and find the **appropriate tab**.

2. **Override** it to change the **tab ordering**.

Comment: Super. I found the solution from your answer. Thank you @Shireen.

Answer (score 2):

Override your `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` block and change the `getRowUrl()` function to include param for `active_tab`.

Here I have set it to the name (group_8) of the *'Prices'* tab.Inspect your prices tab element to find this.

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'),
        'id'=>$row->getId(),
        'active_tab' => 'group_8')
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Geethika. I used `'tab' => 'group_8'` instead of `'active_tab' => 'group_8'`, it worked fine to me.